# Click on div based on $eval throws div click is not a function in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I would like to click one of the `app-meter-tile` displaying in a page (*there are so many `app-meter-tile` listing with data in the page* )  with id `customer-info` or  `offtake` id or a `customer name`. I have tried the below code but throws following error. I would be interested to know how can we click based on `$eval` or access based `xpath` option, please advise.

```
var div = await page.$eval(".mb-10[id='customer-info']",
                element=> element.getAttribute("id"))    
await div.click(".mb-10[id='customer-info']");
```

Timeout or other error:  TypeError: div.click is not a function
    at C:\work\UiTests\offline-login-check.js:59:15
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why your code doen't work**

This method accesses the first element having the provided selector and returns its *id*:

```
var div = await page.$eval(".mb-10[id='customer-info']",
            element=> element.getAttribute("id"))
```

The id is a string and doesn't have a `click` function, of course.

**The correct way to use `page.$eval`**:

```
await page.$eval(".mb-10[id='customer-info']", element => element.click())
```

**Another way to do it** 
is by getting a handle of an element and then clicking it:

```
const div = await page.$(".mb-10[id='customer-info']");
await div.click();
```

Comment: If we need to get the element by name and click it, how can we get that ?

Comment: Just use any `document.querySelector`-compatible selectors, like: `[name=anyName]` or do you mean something else?